# Including a library in both the header file and the cpp file

Tags: c++, header

I am new to C++. I have seen code that includes a library file (`string` as an example) in both the header and cpp file. Will this cause duplicate code if `#ifndef` is not used? or is the preprocessor smart enough to ignore it. Is it normal to include the same library in both files?

test.h

```
#include <string>
.
.
.
```

test.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "test.h"
.
.
.
```

Comment: `<string>` will have its own `ifndef` guards.

Comment: Also, unless you need something from `<string>` in the header it is normal to just include it in the implementation file.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it normal to include the same library in both files?

Yes. It is normal to include a header into multiple files.

Whenever you use a declaration from a header, you should include that header. If you use `std::string`  in `test.h`, then you should include `<string>` in `test.h`. If you use `std::string` in `test.cpp`, then you should in include `<string>` in `test.cpp`. Whether `<string>` happens to be included in one of the headers included by `test.cpp` is irrelevant and is something that shouldn't be relied upon.

> Will this cause duplicate code if `#ifndef` is not used?

If a header doesn't have a header guard, then including it multiple times will indeed cause its content to be duplicated, yes.

> or is the preprocessor smart enough to ignore it.

The preprocessor doesn't ignore any includes. Each include will be processed. A preprocessor may be smart enough to optimise inclusion of a header that it knows would be empty due to an include guard.

Answer (score 2):

All C++ standard library header files have `ifndef` guards.  It is safe to include them in multiple files.

The rule of thumb is to include the file everywhere where its definitions are needed.  This means if you're using `std::string` in both h and cpp files, include `<string>` in both.

For any of your own header files, you should always use `ifndef` guards for the same purpose.

Comment: `assert.h` and `cassert` do not have include guards. They can be included multiple times with different effects depending on whether the macro `NDEBUG` is defined at the point where the header is included.